# Conversion of data on the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Friends,
I am retrieving information from a WebService, using the following method, which returns me a MAP
Future &#706Map &#706String, String >> recoverTypesBenefits () async {...

I want to use it in a DropDown and I am trying to recover it as follows:

```
DropdownButton (
isExpanded: false,
value: dropdownValueBeneficios,
items: (recoverTypesBenefits () as Map <String, String>). entries.map <DropdownMenuItem <String>> ((entry) {...
```

But I'm getting this feedback:

> type 'Future &#706Map &#706String, String >>' is not a subtype of type 'Map &#706String, String>' in type cast

I thought that both MAP &#706String, String> there would be no error.

A detail:
Creating the MAP directly outside FUTURE

```
Map <String, String> tipos = {"": "- Select the type of benefit -"};
```

, and calling this way
    items: tipos.entries.map &#706DropdownMenuItem &#706String>> ((entry) {...
I recover the data correctly. But this way I'm not accessing it dynamically,
of the webservice.

Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Obrigado, João. Pelas orientações.